# Mysql packet too big

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I got the following error:

Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

from a rails webapp.

I have to store really large blobs into db (around 700Mb).

How i can solve? 
I known i have to change max_allowed_packet, but 700mb isn't too much for a single packet?
There is a way to split into multiple packet to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: +1 for "Is there is a way to split [a packet] into multiple packets to avoid memory leaks?" - would like to know this, too.

Comment: Can it be separated by a single insert statement and a couple of update (which adds content to the end of the BLOB field)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think problem is Rails App since error was thrown by MySQL. My suggestion solution would be to save blob data to file instead and associate with model.

https://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fu/wiki

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store blobs that large then you'll need to change your max_allowed_packet to make that possible. The fact that this goes against your intuition is probably a sign that you should reconsider putting blobs of that size in MySQL. I personally don't think that's a good idea.